# laravel making its own route to blade file

Tags: php, laravel

working a project with Laravel 5.6.
the problem is, when im going to an url like:

/login

or any other route and specify where it should go, it making its own route and going to another place. no metter if i even clear the code of that blade file.

i have not several routes or blade file that are the same. i have cleared my browser cache, laravel cach, config cache, and the command:

php artisan route:cache
did not worked to clear route cache.

my code example: web.php code

```
Route::get("/login", "LoginController@login");
```

Example: LoginController.php code

```
public function login()
{
   return view('/login'); // not going to this path
}
```

to conclude, it does not read my code :(
need your ideas!

Comment: Can you update your web.php code here ?

Comment: Route::get('/login', 'controller@login');
the web.php code looks like this

Comment: Update your question with web.php and controller login method code

Comment: Yes, thats wrong .. you should change  the name of the controller "controller" to a specific name like: "ArticleController"

Comment: @keizah updated, i dont think that would be the problem.

Comment: @rook99 that is just an example, the controller has another name ;)

Comment: return view('login'); your file name is login.blade.php? what do you see in the browser?

Comment: @keizah yes. another page. for many routes, i see the same page

Answer (score 0):

```
public function login()
{
   return view('login'); 
}
```

view accepts the view name not the path of the route, If you want go to any route use redirect("/route_name") . But in your case if you redirect to login route again it will throw exception because the login route again calls this function. so you need to pass the view name. for example:
if your login view is in 
resources
  - views
    -login.blade.php
then use above code. or if the login page is in any other folder inside view
it will be like `return view("foldername.login")`

Comment: login in return line is the name of the blade file.

Comment: it was working fine, but now, if i go to any route, it shows me another page

Comment: what another page?? Explain please

Comment: i want it to go to login.blade.php which is in root directory, but it goes to another page which is stored into another folder called market and the file called index. now every url is showing me this file. i this the problem is from route (maybe its cache) because when i even remove the route (/login), it still working and showing me that page

Comment: Did you put all your routes in auth middleware?? please share web.php ....